# Netbeans: Transferring Maven Repository index: Central - stuck at 0%

Tags: java, maven

I'm unable to get the Central Maven repo index.  I'm running Netbeans 7.0.1 and have tried rebooting my PC, rebooting Netbeans 4 times and [alternate mirrors](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories).  It sits at 0% and never goes anywhere and never throws an error.  I'm unsure what to try or what to investigate to try to determine the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move the local-Repository-path to another place, in the file: conf/settings.xml

```
<localRepository>D:/mvn_repo</localRepository>
```

Also check maven's configuration.

Comment: I don't see this setting inside of settings.xml

Comment: So add this node to your settings.xml

Answer (score 24):

How to Stop Netbeans: Transferring repository index
I see at status bar, that Netbeans is Transferring repository index : java.net repository. It slows down my computer very much. Very annoying.

Solution for Netbeans 7.4 (and possibly later versions, 8.0):
Tools | Options | Java | Maven | Index”, find “Index Update Frequency” and then adjust how often it should be updated (Never :).

Answer (score 6):

From Netbeans Settings Options->Java->Maven you can set the indexing to never.  How exactly that relates to 'Completely disable' I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem myself, it turned out to be the proxy settings (Tools/Options/Proxy settings).

Answer (score 2):

Add `-J-Djava.io.tmpdir=T:/Temp` to the end of the `netbeans_default_options` property in `NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf` configuration file, assuming that `T:\` has a lot more space than `C:\`.