# Downloads from Maven central repository not working

Tags: maven, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 and Maven 3.0.4. For some reason, my computer can't download dependencies or even the repository index. When I run a project and Maven tries to download a repository e.g. from "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.6/junit-4.6.jar", the progress indicator is stuck at 0%. The same thing happens when Maven tries to download the repository index.

Basically, I have the same problem as in this question: [Netbeans: Transferring Maven Repository index: Central - stuck at 0%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875028/netbeans-transferring-maven-repository-index-central-stuck-at-0), but the selected answer doesn't work for me. I have also tried using a different mirror, but nothing seems to work.

---

**SOLVED**

Ok, turns out my AVG Anti-Virus 2012 was somehow stopping the downloads. Disabling AVG solved the problem. More specifically, I think it was the LinkScanner module of AVG that was responsible for stopping the downloads.

Comment: no, at least I don't think so

Comment: Needs more detail about your system and what you've tried.  Does `wget http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.6/junit-4.6.jar` work?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Entering the address into my browser works just fine, and placing the downloaded file in the right local directory works as well, but this manual method gets a bit tedious.

I've tried using a mirror, by changing the settings in settings.xml, but this resulted in the same behavoiur, only with a different remote repo. I've also tried reinstalling netbeans, and using an older version, but nothing has helped so far. 

What kind of info would be helpful if i posted? My pom.xml?

Comment: The process works fine on my other computer, using the same internet connection, by the way