# Netbeans keeps transferring maven repository index, even though I have disabled it

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

Although I have set "Index Update Frequency" to "[Never](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26879923/69537)":

[image]

Netbeans frequently tries to transfer maven repository index which consumes a lot of my bandwidth:

[image]

Is it fine if I check "Completely disable indexing" option? It says that it's not recommended and many features will be limited. What features will be limited exactly?

Comment: @vels4j netbeans version: 8.0.2

Comment: Did you ever let it go and index the repo? At least one time!

Comment: @liponcio No. Because it consumes a lot of bandwidth and takes a lot of time to complete.

Comment: Ok, Did you check the check box bellow the index update frequency?

Answer (score 16):

> What features will be limited exactly?

- ***You may not get the latest versions of dependencies when typing
  control space in the version tag in the pom.xml file.***
- ***The functionality to "Search dependency at Maven Repositories for .." in the Java editor may not find the dependency you are looking for.***

In Netbeans 8.2 I selected "Completely disable indexing" and it's all working for me besides the above.

I can understand why it's ***NOT recommended***, but I keeps on running out of space on my SSD drive.
It keeps downloading the index over and over again in a loop...

[image]